# Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.ui.internal.StandardTrim' from bundle '485' : Eclipse RCP Product based on features

Tags: eclipse, product, rcp, eclipse-emf

I am developing Eclipse RCP Application on a custom target platform that contains plugins of EMF, Sphinx, Artop and other features.

I am using Eclipse 2021-09 and OpenJdk17.

There is a product file based on features which works fine when I launch it as Eclipse Application. But when I export the product, I get it all exported but it is not working well.

The tool should show AUTOSAR Perspective with checking a license, but it does not show me anything.
And There are some messages as the following in the .log file.

```
    MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.ui.internal.StandardTrim' from bundle '485'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in com.autron.odin.common.ui was unable to load class com.autron.odin.common.ui.perspectives.ArtopPerspectiveFactory.
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:995)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:344)
.
.
.
.
.
Caused by: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in com.autron.odin.common.ui was unable to load class com.autron.odin.common.ui.perspectives.ArtopPerspectiveFactory.
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:995)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.inject(ContextInjectionFactory.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:1469)
.
.
.
.

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in com.autron.odin.common.ui was unable to load class com.autron.odin.common.ui.perspectives.ArtopPerspectiveFactory.
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.PerspectiveDescriptor.createFactory(PerspectiveDescriptor.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.createPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:4105)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busySetPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:4012)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.lambda$10(WorkbenchPage.java:3972)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:3972)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setup(WorkbenchWindow.java:898)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

I have my product file with the following settings.

```
  <configurations>
      <plugin id="org.apache.felix.scr" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.console" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.update.configurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="3" />
   </configurations>
```

I'd really appreciate for your support.
I've been struggling with this more than 3 days..

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that everything you use is ready for Java 17? Java 17 is more restrictive than older version and some Java code has to be adapted for Java 17.

Comment: Are you sure the class `com.autron.odin.common.ui.perspectives.ArtopPerspectiveFactory` is being included in the build? Are all the plug-ins it depends on (directly or indirectly) being included?

Comment: I got it fixed by creating all the projects again with JDK-17 and putting all the version in the feature.